# Take an array of phone numbers and search another array for each occurrence of said number and print that matching line and the following line

Tags: regex, perl

I have two text files. I'm importing each file into an array. Each value in the numbers array should search the users array for its match. If found echo the matching line and the proceeding line.

So, if the first entry in the numbers array is 1234, search users array for 1234. If found print that line and the next.

numbers.txt looks like:

```
1234567021
1234566792
```

users filelooks like:

```
1234567021@host.com User-Password == "secret"
           Framed-IP-Address = 000.000.000.000,
```

What I have so far:

```
use strict;

my $users_file = "users";
my $numbers_file = "numbers.txt";
my $phonenumber;
my $numbers;


#### Place phone number into an array ####
open (RESULTS, $numbers_file) or die "Unable to open file: $users_file\n$!";
my @numbers;
@numbers = <NUMBER_RESULTS>;
close(NUMBER_RESULTS);

#### Place users file contents into an array ####
open (RESULTS, $users_file) or die "Unable to open file: $users_file\n$!";
my @users_data;
@users_data = <RESULTS>;
close(RESULTS);


#### Search the array for the string ####
foreach $numbers(@users_data) {
    if (index($numbers,$phonenumber) ge 0) {
  my @list = grep /\b$numbers\b/, @users_data;
  chomp @list;
  print "$_\n" foreach @list;
    }
}


exit 1;
```

Comment: You have given 2 different requirements for what to print.  At one spot you say the line **after** the match.  In another spot, you say the line **before**.  Which is it?

Comment: The line of the match, and the line following the match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are recreating a search for a key when perl has a built-in hash data type that will handle this better and faster than rolling your own.  Using this will take a little more work in reading in the data, but it will be worth it.

First, lets switch to a modern version of [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) where we use a lexically scoped variable for the file handle, and specify a mode.

```
open (my $results, "<", $users_file) or die "Unable to open file: $users_file\n$!";
```

From there, we will read the file open line at a time and populate the hash.

```
my (%users_data, $number, $number_line);
while(<$results>)
{
    chomp;
    if(defined($number))
    {
        $user_data{$number} = "$number_line\t$_\n";    #load the line after the number into the hash value.
        undef $number;
    }else
    {
        if(/^(\d+)\@/)     #match digits between the beginning of the line and the @ symbol.
        {
            $number = $1;    #save matched digits from $1.
            $number_line = $_;
    }
}
```

Note that this is assuming that the data is well formated.  If there are concerns, you can test for proper formatting in the else clause.

Now, for the output we can use the following

```
for (@numbers)
{
    chomp;    #since we didn't remove newlines when populating @numbers
    if( defined($users_data{$_}) )
    {
        print $users_data{$_};
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a working version.  Note `use strict` and `use warnings` helped to catch that one variables was declared (`RESULTS` and `%users_file`) while another was used later (`NUMBER_RESULTS` and `%user_file`), which is why those are so important.  Also `Data::Dumper` was used to print out the contents of the array `@numbers` and the hash `%users_data` to see what data actually made it into the data structures.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use Data::Dumper;

my $users_file = "users";
my $numbers_file = "numbers.txt";

#### Place phone number into an array ####
open (my $results, "<", $numbers_file) or die "Unable to open file: $numbers_file\n$!";
my @numbers;
@numbers = <$results>;
close($results);
#print Dumper \@numbers;

open (my $results, "<", $users_file) or die "Unable to open file: $users_file\n$!";
my (%users_data, $number, $number_line);
while(<$results>)
{
    chomp;
    if(defined($number))
    {
        $users_data{$number} = $number_line."\n$_\n";    #load the line after the number into the hash value.
        undef $number;
    }else
    {
        if(/^(\d+)\@/)     #match digits between the beginning of the line and the @ symbol.
        {
            $number = $1;    #save matched digits from $1.
            $number_line = $_;
        }
    }
}
#print Dumper \%users_data;

for (@numbers)
{
    chomp;    #since we didn't remove newlines when populating @numbers
    if( defined($users_data{$_}) )
    {
        print $users_data{$_};
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to import the numbers file into an array or list. Then search for each number in the user_data file. When found print the line and the following line.

Comment: I tried your example but its not returning anything. code: http://pastebin.com/ec9j8Shg

Comment: @AndrewTaylor I assumed that the important part was to print the numbers that matched and the following lines (which this does).  Do you **really** need to load the users_data into an array?

Comment: @AndrewTaylor Can you edit your question to include a couple of lines of each of the files so I can see how it is formatted.  If you aren't getting anything, then there is a formatting mismatch which is causing `defined($users_data{$_})` to fail that we need to deal with.

Comment: @AndrewTaylor BTW, do you have `use warnings;` in your script?  Are you getting any warnings?

Comment: Degustaf, no it does not need to be an array. Basically I want to search the users file for the number and list its ip address contained on the second line.

Comment: @AndrewTaylor I edited the code to handle the format of the files.

Comment: Degustaf, thank you for your time. However, It's still not returning anything. I have pasted the entire code of the script into this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/g0QHu8fR . The phone numbers are basic 10 digit numbers one on each line. The users file is formatted like this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/5rjJ4EtY